# Specifying R1C1 in Excel using Variables in a For...Next Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a For Next loop that pulls specific numbers from specific cells in order to calculate total hours for a time card using Excel (it's the best program for what I'm using it for). I cannot, however figure out how to do it because I'm using R1C1 because I'm running the a count for the locations. I am not hidebound to this particular method of doing things, but a variation on it worked in Access (but I can't use Access for this because, reasons).

Attached is the code snippet I'm using.

```
For Weekday = 11 To 17  'Determine the day of the week by Row Reference (R1C1 format)
    For DayValue = 29 To 34     'Determin time input (Call, Meal In, Meal Out, Wrap, etc.) for day of the week
        WrkTimes(DayValue) = ActiveSheet.Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "R" & (Weekday) & "C" & (DayValue) 'Select the correct time input
    Next DayValue   'Process the next time input    
    TotHrs(Weekday) = WrkTimes(34) - WrkTimes(29) - (WrkTimes(31) - WrkTimes(30)) - (WrkTimes(33) - WrkTimes(32))   'Calculate total hours for the day
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Weekday, 37) = TotHrs(Weekday)    'Display total hours for the day in the proper cell
```

Yes there is a Next command at the bottom of this loop, I just have other non-relevant code between this and the end. I'm getting the error on the DayValue lines

Comment: What about `WrkTimes(DayValue) = ActiveSheet.Cells(Weekday, DayValue).Value`? I *think* that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not pulling the value of that cell. I am getting a Subscript out of Range error when I try to run it and I'm not getting the value I'm needing out of the cell.

Essentially the formula should (pulling cell values) look like:
TotHrs(Weekday)=22.0-8.0-(14.5-14.0)-(0.0-0.0)
Resulting in a value for TotHrs(Weekday) of 13.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is to use

```
Cells(r, c)
```

Then you can put in your offsets such as

```
Cells(r-3, c)
```

You would just need to store the r and c values, which you've done as Weekday (r) and DayValue (c).

---

In the case if what you're looking at with the loop:

```
Cells(Weekday, DayValue).Value
```

This would give the value in the cell you've referenced.

---

**Edit:**

Suggestion from my comment:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, k as Long
For Weekday = 11 To 17
    i = Cells(Weekday, 34).Value 'Should allow you to have an output for each row
    For DayValue = 33 To 29 Step -1 'Saving column 34 outside of the dayvalue loop
        j = i
        k = Cells(Weekday, DayValue).Value
        i = j - k
    Next DayValue
    Cells(Weekday, 37).Value = i
Next Weekday
```

Comment: So, I did your recommendation (thank you for that) and it's locating the appropriate cell. It's not, however pulling the value of that cell.

Comment: @LorenBentley See Edit in my post for my suggestion.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify why I kept getting the subscript out of range (after following the suggestions from Scott and Phylogenesis), it turns out that my Weekday(x) was set for 7 when it should have been set at 17.

Thanks for all the help.